# When I select alum for example it stores it and then when I select mild metal it shows both values (after all the calculations are done)

Tags: javascript

```js
sum = {
  "al": 12,
  "mm": 20,
  "hm": 30,
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when page loads
    document.getElementById("tensile").addEventListener("click", function(e) { 
        var tgt = e.target; // what was clicked
        if (tgt.name == "size") { // is it one of the radios?
            var val = tgt.value; // save the value once (DRY principle)
  
            $('.ck').click(function(){
                var a = parseFloat($('.n1').val());
                var b = parseFloat($('.n2').val());
                var z = 3.14;
                var c = a * b * z * sum[val];
                alert(c);
            })
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Diameter<input type="text" class="n1" /><br />
Metal Thickness<input type="text" class="n2" /><br />

<h3> Select Metal </h3>
<form id="tensile">
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="al">Alum
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="mm">Mild Metal<br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="hm"> Heavy Metal<br>
  <br>
</form>
<hr />

<input type="button" value="Add" class="ck" />
```

Comment: Don't add a click handler inside another click handler.

Comment: Why are you mixing JavaScript `addEventListener` with jQuery `click()`? Pick one approach.

Comment: There's no need for the `tensile` event listener. Just do the `.ck` click listener.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem". The current title **is** the problem, and belongs in the question. A title should talk about the technical aspects of what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Barmar! Are you referring to this line of code:

document.getElementById("tensile").addEventListener("click", function(e) {   ??

If I delete that it doesn't click anymore. 

Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry Heretic Monkey. This is my first question ever posted on stack overflow. I am very new to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to this, it will work:

the reason you got the previous calculation
and the second one after it, is because each time you click on the radio button you create a new `event listener` to the `add` button, so when you click it two handlers are running that is why you get 2 alerts. pull the event listener of the `add` button out, and you will have only one handler for it:

```js
sum = {
  "al": 12,
  "mm": 20,
  "hm": 30,
}
let val;
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when page loads  
  document.getElementById("tensile").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var tgt = e.target; // what was clicked
    if (tgt.name == "size") { // is it one of the radios?
      val = tgt.value; // save the value once (DRY principle) 
    }
  })

  $('.ck').click(function() {
    var a = parseFloat($('.n1').val());
    var b = parseFloat($('.n2').val());
    var z = 3.14;
    var c = a * b * z * sum[val];
    alert(c);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Diameter<input type="text" class="n1" /><br /> Metal Thickness<input type="text" class="n2" /><br />

<h3> Select Metal </h3>
<form id="tensile">
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="al">Alum
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="mm">Mild Metal<br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="hm"> Heavy Metal<br>
  <br>
</form>
<hr />

<input type="button" value="Add" class="ck" />
```

Comment: Thank you @Ben.S That wooorked!! Awesome thanks dude. I tried to give you an upvote but it doesn't let me because I am new.

Comment: I edited the answer, @Skorpios please check the answer, the V sign

Comment: Thank you. Are you able to tell me how to pull the event listener of the add button out and have only one handler for it please?

Comment: Sorry I dont see a V sign anywhere?

Comment: yes, first you can open my code snippet and see. but in short after you write `window.addEventListener("load", function() {` 
you add the `click event` of the radio buttons. after you close the event listener of the radio buttons. then write this: 
`$('.ck').click(function() {
    var a = parseFloat($('.n1').val());
    var b = parseFloat($('.n2').val());
    var z = 3.14;
    var c = a * b * z * sum[val];
    alert(c);
  })`

also put the `val` variable before the `window.addEventListener` line

Comment: the V sign is right after the downvote sign (it's grayed )

Comment: @Skorpios did you understand how to put the event listener out ?

Comment: Yes, I understood and I pressed on the check mark for you that means you answered my question! Thanks!